# How to test Obfuscated app which runs via Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, testing, mono

As its known Mono is an fork of .NET Framework but with nuances, such as some things could be not implemented or not working in some versions of Mono, probably everywhere idk (eg `Environment.FailFast`), what if someone will decide to use this `Environment.FailFast` and add it in obfuscation process, for that this guy who did that should run game server (some standalone) to test it or check sources of Mono with necessary version of Unity (this will take some time to do that).

Obfuscator that obfuscates .NET application (Mono .DLL, eg: `.NET Framework 4.7.2`) which is runs on Unity Engine, how do I could test that after obfuscation it runs without errors/crashes? Currently Im just running standalone (game server of `Unturned`) that doing that for me, after that waiting for a few minutes then I will see the result - this is very long process for me, to spend 1-2 minutes to test obfuscated .DLL.

### Problems

What if someone would ask: "hey, how do I trust you If I cant see real tests such as Unit Tests that proves me that my program works after obfuscation without any problems".

What if I want to prove to myself that obfuscation working fine and just running without errors and crashes would be great.

### Current ideas

1. Write custom Unity game and then test there my things (Use native mono api to load assembly or Assembly.Load of the dll then create new GameObject in both situations etc).
2. Install `Mono` then open up `cmd` or somewhere else path where is `Mono` located then create simple console app write there simple logic of loading .DLL then compiling app in Visual Studio after that writing in `cmd`

> mono "path_to_the_compiled_executable_in_VS.exe"

### Issues of current ideas

1. This is hard to support, thats means I have to store plenty of different version of my custom Unity game somewhere - I guess in obfuscator project. (eg Unity 2019.?.?/2019.?.?/2020/2021 etc) (then write in these games some scripts to load assembly and run game). Always I will have to wait till game will load. (I mean the Unity load menu with Unity Logo, surely this is could be removed with some ways, but I dont wanna do that).
2. Im sure Unity is differs from Mono 100%, but I may be wrong (I mean the some implementations of Mono eg Assembly reading/loading and other things). So, Im not able to create there real `GameObjects` of .DLL to invoke methods such as `Update/Awake/OnEnable/OnDisable` etc, perhaps there are something that could do that and this would be cool.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is the single answer I got asking directly in some reversing discord channels, but I didnt test it yet, Im sure this is a great idea, will be great to hear other ideas.

### Answer that I got **By kotae in BitCrackers discord**

what are you obfuscating? if it's the file on disk then why do you need unity Update/Awake/OnEnable/OnDisable events? when compatibility is your concern, target the lowest supported version. i think this is usually .NET 4.5. mono has near 100% coverage of everything in .NET 4.5, and there are lists on the mono site you can find to confirm that.
besides that, for unit tests here's what i'd do:

1. keep a list of all .NET features you use (types, methods, etc)
2. keep a collection of all versions of mono that unity ships with (i'm pretty sure there's only been 2 but could be wrong - check file hashes)
3. write a test runner that loads each mono.dll, initializes a runtime environment, and then uses reflection (either .NET reflection or just native mono api calls) to run through your list from step#1 and make sure each item exists
   you could automate step#1 using reflection as well, actually, or just manual parsing of the IL. mono.cecil or something similar would let you examine the IL, then you just have to pattern match instructions that reference .NET types & methods & whatever else.

[about-mono compatibility](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/)

### My conclusions

I made some conclusions for myself, and one of them is there are no need Update/Awake/OnEnable/OnDisable events, sadly I dont have ideas on how to test the application in depth (I mean execute methods, test everything as it conceived by the developer of this application), so I wanted is just to see how the application runs under Unity (does it has errors/crashes this is enough for me). If I will get other answers outside I will post them here.